# Exception like java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: fromIndex(XXX) > toIndex(XX)

Tags: java

I have a jqgrid, with pagination. User can enter data by themselves to neviaget between pages.

I am getting error if user enter more than available pages on line 199 as shown in the above example. How to solve this issue?

```
if(noOfRows != null && !recipeList.isEmpty())
        if ((noOfRows * pageNo) < recipeList.size()) {
            recipeList = recipeList.subList((noOfRows * (pageNo - 1)),
                    (noOfRows * pageNo));
        } else {
            recipeList = recipeList.subList((noOfRows * (pageNo - 1)), 
                    recipeList.size());  //line 199:  giving error
        }
    for (Recipe recp : recipeList) {
             ..............
             ..............
```

I tried to change the else part of code where on line 199 :

```
  int totalCustomPagesNums=noOfRows * (pageNo - 1); 
        int firstIndex=totalCustomPagesNums < recipeIdList.size()?totalCustomPagesNums:1;
        recipeList = recipeList.subList(firstIndex,
         recipeList.size());
```

Comment: By checking that the entered number is valid.

Comment: if `(noOfRows * (pageNo - 1)) > recipeList.size()`, that would be your problem

Comment: @JBNizet yes fine , i think that i know. But problem is how? I tried above but i did not work

Comment: @Stewart Yes that is problem.

Comment: Start by telling us what is entered by the user. and what all these variables are. If I read your question correctly, you need `if (enteredNumber <= availablePages)` somewhere.

Comment: @JBNizet I hope this makes sense http://my.jetscreenshot.com/demo/20140221-2boj-58kb.jpg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would simplify it to:

- Work out the lower bound, which must be at least 0 and at most `recipeList.size()`
- Work out the exclusive upper bound, which must be at least 0 and at most `recipeList.size()`
- Take the sublist

So:

```
int start = Math.min(Math.max(noOfRows * (pageNo - 1), 0), recipeList.size());
int end = Math.min(Math.max(noOfRows * pageNo, start), recipeList.size());
recipeList = recipeList.subList(start, end);
```

Now you know for sure that `0 <= start <= end <= recipeList.size()`, so it'll be fine, even if the user specifies bizarre row counts or page numbers.

Comment: http://my.jetscreenshot.com/demo/20140221-2boj-58kb.jpg

Comment: @Sundara: And my code won't break on that. It will display an empty page, but it won't break. You'll end up with both `start` and `end` being `recipeList.size()`.

Comment: shall i put your code in else part?

Comment: @Sundara: No, my code replaces your whole if/else.

Comment: Did you mean starting from my first line to line no 199(as i specified in above question code) ? your code replaces that?

Comment: @Sundara: No, replacing the if/else where you take a sublist.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create a sublist that starts at index 100 and ends at index 72. Since the beginning of your list is behind the end, you are getting the IllegalArgumentException.

Add another check, if `(noOfRows*pageNo < recipeList.size())`.

Answer (score 0):

I would add two extra blocks, to the beginning of your code.

```
if (pageNo < 1) {
    pageNo = 1;
}

if ((pageNo - 1) * noOfRows >= recipeList.size()) {
    pageNo = 1 + ( recipeList.size() - 1 ) / noOfRows;
}
```

The first block fixes things if the page number is too low.  The second block fixes things if the page number is too high.

The check at the beginning of the second block is making sure that the index of the first recipe to be displayed (which is `(pageNo - 1) * noOfRows`) is within the range of `recipeList`.  The assignment inside is setting `pageNo` to the highest value for which this is true.